# Is there icon for "Set Default"

Tags: icon

I've been using many icons to make buttons through my application distinct and easier to understand(by using common icon), but one button struck into my mind: "Set Default" button. I couldn't find anything like icon for this, and I wonder if it exists or how it possibly can be expressed as a pictograph.

**EDIT:**
To clarify what I mean: default here meant as default in list of values, not a default value:

- Item 1 <- default
- Item 2 <- set default button with default icon
- Item 3< - set default button with default icon
- Item 4 <- set default button with default icon

Answer (score 4):

Ran a search for *"default"* on the Noun Project and i got a [reset](https://thenounproject.com/term/reset/538854/) and a [home](https://thenounproject.com/term/homepage/696716/) as good ideas.

Answer (score 4):

You can show this way also a gear inside and a 3 arrow turning round (getting back setting or previous settings)

[image]

or

[image]

Comment: I like this icon, it implies repeat-ability and a setting in one, what your default is.

Comment: So it should be clockwise? Or no.  I mean arrows direction

Answer (score 2):

How about an "undo"-like symbol? Actually Gimp uses such a symbol:

[image: set default GIMP]

Comment: Then it should be undo all like icon. No?

Answer (score 0):

icon to set as default if you want to add color you should use SVG

> `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <svg width="700pt" height="700pt" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 700 700" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> <g> <path d="m559.62 298.67h33.043v-37.332h-38.285c-2.1484-23.875-8.4766-46.5-18.105-67.293l33.207-19.172-18.668-32.332-33.188 19.152c-13.535-19.098-30.184-35.785-49.297-49.297l19.172-33.188-32.332-18.668-19.172 33.207c-20.812-9.6328-43.457-15.961-67.332-18.125v-38.289h-37.332v38.285c-23.875 2.1484-46.5 8.4766-67.312 18.105l-19.172-33.188-32.332 18.668 19.152 33.172c-19.098 13.535-35.766 30.184-49.297 49.297l-33.172-19.133-18.684 32.312 33.207 19.172c-9.6328 20.812-15.941 43.438-18.105 67.312h-38.266l-0.023438 37.332h38.285c2.1484 23.875 8.4922 46.516 18.125 67.332l-33.207 19.152 18.668 32.348 33.188-19.172c13.516 19.098 30.184 35.785 49.297 49.297l-19.152 33.172 32.332 18.684 19.172-33.207c20.812 9.6328 43.418 15.941 67.293 18.105v38.289h37.332v-33.02c24.172 42 69.402 70.355 121.33 70.355 77.336 0 140-62.664 140-140 0.003906-51.934-28.371-97.164-70.371-121.34zm-209.62 168c-102.93 0-186.67-83.738-186.67-186.67s83.738-186.67 186.67-186.67 186.67 83.738 186.67 186.67c0 2.707-0.29688 5.3203-0.39062 7.9883-14.504-5.0781-30.035-7.9883-46.273-7.9883-16.707 0-32.668 3.0781-47.508 8.457 0.26172-2.8359 0.83984-5.5625 0.83984-8.457 0-51.559-41.777-93.332-93.332-93.332-51.559 0-93.332 41.777-93.332 93.332 0 51.559 41.777 93.332 93.332 93.332 2.8945 0 5.6172-0.59766 8.457-0.85938-5.375 14.859-8.457 30.801-8.457 47.523 0 16.238 2.9102 31.754 7.9883 46.273-2.6719 0.097657-5.2852 0.39844-7.9922 0.39844zm17.434-114.26c-5.6172 1.3477-11.422 2.2617-17.434 2.2617-41.234 0-74.668-33.434-74.668-74.668s33.434-74.668 74.668-74.668 74.668 33.434 74.668 74.668c0 6.0312-0.91406 11.816-2.2578 17.434-23.113 12.75-42.227 31.863-54.977 54.973zm122.57 188.93c-67.012 0-121.33-54.32-121.33-121.33s54.32-121.33 121.33-121.33 121.33 54.32 121.33 121.33-54.32 121.33-121.33 121.33z"/> <path d="m569.18 373.8-13.195-13.199-92.383 92.402-39.594-39.613-13.195 13.219 52.789 52.789z"/> </g> </svg>`

[image: set as default]